# XML errors and Java(TM) Platform SE Binary crashing

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, user-interface

So last night I was creating an android XML file to show an edit text and toggle buttons.
Then today when I launched eclipse and opened my project the XML graphical layout was showing:

```
The rendering target (Android 4.2) is still loading.
The layout will refresh automatically once the process is finished.
```

I even hadn't typed a single word yet when I got the error

```
Java(TM) Platform SE Binary has crashed
```

And Eclipse returned an error dialog

```
Java was started but returned exit code=255
C:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar
C:\Users\<name>\Desktop\Android\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launch
er_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
C:\Users\<name>\Desktop\Android\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.1.v
201209141800\splash.bmp
-launcher C:\Users\<name>\Desktop\Android\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
-launcher.library
C:\Users\<name>\Desktop\Android\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launch
er.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813\eclipse_1503.dll
-startup
C:\Users\<name>\Desktop\Android\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launch
er_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata b24_5c
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.mobile.product
-vm C:\Windows\system32\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-jar
C:\Users\<name>\Desktop\Android\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launch
er_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

Well I don't understand what it says and now I'm unable to launch eclipse.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Had similiar java exit code and error when hovering over java objects. Not sure if you have the same problem, but since the error is pretty the same my solution will maybe work for you. I added "-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla" to my eclipse.ini

Comment: Just amazing that the program becomes unusable if it can't render this little popup!

Answer (score 1):

Set the below property in eclipse.ini has resoled this problem
-Dcom.ibm.ws.management.event.max_polling_interval=1000

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Windows 8.1 Professional x64 and I was getting the same annoying error, I tried to execute Eclipse by using **Troubleshoot compatibility** (right click on eclipse.exe) then I chose the option "execute in Windows 8 Mode" and up now, this workaround has solved the problem...

Answer (score 0):

This error is also caused by a damage on ntdll.dll that happens whenever you're trying to install Sony Vaio Drivers on Windows 8.1.
That crash also affects other apps like Windows Media Player, BSPlayer, Catalist Control Center and all of them gets solved when they're executed by using troubleshoot compatibility option as mentioned on previous answer...
I got rid of this issue by not installing all Sony drivers. It seems that Sony Vaio model VPCSB25FB doesn't fully support Windows 8.1 yet. Mainly, when you install Windows 8.1 directly, with no upgrade from Windows 8 or 7...